# Google test XML report doesn't reflect crashed tests

Tags: unit-testing, googletest

I am using Google test framework for unit testing and am generating an XML report of the tests. The XML being parsed by Jenkins. I've been noticed recently that some of my unit tests were crashed during execution with Segmentation fault. The crashed tests generated XML's as well with no failure entry., therefore I have not running tests marked as passed. I need a way to generate XML with a failure in this case, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I googled for "[google test segmentation fault failed tests](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+test+segmentation+fault+failed+tests)" and found a guide on googletest. The [propagating fatal failures](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Propagating_Fatal_Failures) section might help you solve your problem.